# powershell GCI access denied

Tags: windows, powershell, search

Trying to see my files larger than 500mb inside **C:\users**

```
Get-ChildItem C:\users\cata\ -recurse | where-object {$_.length -gt 500mb} | Sort-Object length | ft fullname, length -auto

FullName                                                                                                                                                            
Length
--------                                                                                                                                                            
------
C:\users\cata\Downloads\Masters of Science\Masters of Science Fiction.avi 1204361216
```

As you can see a little bit below, it **doesn't search** inside hidden folders like AppData.

However, searching explicit in **appdata** lists an item which previously hasn't been listed.

```
Get-ChildItem C:\users\cata\appdata -recurse | where-object {$_.length -gt 500mb} | Sort-Object length | ft fullname, length -auto
FullName                                                                     
Length
--------                                                                     
------
C:\users\cata\appdata\Roaming\tobedeleted\CentOS-6.0-x86_64-bin-DVD1.iso 4238800896
```

And if I try to search with **-force** parameter, it says access denied, even though I can manually go inside the appdata directory.
Is it possible to force powershell to go inside the hidden directories such as C:\Users\cata\AppData and search for files?

Comment: you wrote However.... then stopped. Your question is incomplete. Can you edit your statement, it is not complete and clearly understandable.

Comment: Yea, sorry. I've edited just now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `-Force` parameter from an elevated instance of Powershell. Open PS as an administrator, then use `-Force` (you may also want to use `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`.

```
Get-ChildItem C:\users\cata -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```